# Export to csv in debug mode success but in run-time mode it fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, csv

I am reading records from a SQL Server table into a dataset and then exporting it to a CSV file. When I step through it in debug mode, everything works fine. When I run it, it exports just one cell with crap data. Since it is an ASP.NET application I am not sure if I am doing something wrong regarding postbacks. It seems in run-time, it doesn't wait for the CSV file to be written.

```vb
Dim sbldRecordCSV As New StringBuilder

Dim dtHCMTable As DataTable = mdsHCMTable.Tables(0)
Dim intIndex As Integer = 0

'Read the connection-string from web.config
Dim connHCM As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connHCM").ConnectionString)

'Read the exported CSV file path from web.config
Dim strCSVpath As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CSVpath").ToString

Try
    For intIndex = 0 To mdsHCMTable.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim drHCMTable As DataRow = dtHCMTable.Rows(intIndex)
        For Each field As Object In drHCMTable.ItemArray
            sbldRecordCSV.Append(field.ToString & "|")
        Next
        sbldRecordCSV.Replace("|", vbNewLine, sbldRecordCSV.Length - 1, 1)
    Next

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(strCSVpath.ToString & lstDataTables.SelectedValue.ToString & ".csv", sbldRecordCSV.ToString, False)
```

Comment: Where in that code are you actually retrieving any data from the database?  You create a `SqlConnection` but never use it, so any data in that `DataTable` must be already there from earlier.  You may have run that code in the debugger but you clearly never debugged it.

Comment: Hi jmcihinney, the procedure heading is Protected Sub ExportRecordsToCSV(mdsHCMTable As DataSet). I retrieve the dataset as a parameter. And please, no need to comment anything about my debugging abilities. i am new to asp.net but not new to programming. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: I can only go by what I see.  You have tagged this question with SQL and with SQL Server but the method in question receives and already-populated `DataSet`, so the question has nothing at all to do with SQL or SQL Server.  You create a `SqlConnection` object that you never use, but you never picked that up in your debugging.  Based on what you've shown us, I can only conclude that your `DataSet` doesn't contain what you think it does.  If it was me, I'd be adding some tracing code to see what is actually happening when the Release build is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching around I realized that I neede to modify the ExportCSV code. The modified routine is as follows:

Protected Sub ExportToCSV(mdsHCMTable As DataSet)
        Dim dt As DataTable = mdsHCMTable.Tables(0)

```
    'Read the exported CSV file path from web.config
    Dim strCSVpath As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CSVpath").ToString

    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & lstDataTables.SelectedValue.ToString & ".csv")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/text"

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        'add separator
        sb.Append(dt.Columns(k).ColumnName + "|"c)
    Next
    'append new line
    sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            'add separator
            sb.Append(dt.Rows(i)(k).ToString().Replace(",", "|") + "|"c)
        Next
        'append new line
        sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    Next

    Response.Clear()
    Response.BufferOutput = False
    Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
End Sub
```

This solution worked for me. I hope it can be helpful to others.